# CKEditor, IE9 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, ckeditor

I am using the latest version of CKEditor (CKEditor 3.6.3, released on 17 April 2012) on my site.

It works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome and IE9 without any modification.

It works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome when I customize the toolbar, but then I get the following error message (I translated it) in IE9:

```
"SCRIPT5007: Cannot retrieve the value of property length, the object is null or undefined. 
ckeditor.js, line 11101 token 21"
```

And that is the following line:

```
var w=o.toolbox.toolbars,x=o.config.toolbar instanceof Array ? o.config.toolbar : o.config['toolbar_'+o.config.toolbar];
    for(var y=0;y<x.length;y++){
```

So somehow the variable `x` is not an `Array` in IE9: I've tried IE7, 8 and 9 various modes all have the same error.

And it seems that IE9 is also the only browser that does not execute the following line:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {}
```

Is this a familiar problem (if so, how can I fix it) or is it a bug in CKEditor?

Comment: Welcome to SO, take a look at [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for better formatting of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your configuration you have a syntax error, for example a trailing comma.